# Yii2 Codeception - exception when running REST test

Tags: yii, yii2, code-coverage, yii2-advanced-app, codeception

I have some troubles running codeception coverage for Api tests, tests without coverage work just fine using config below:

Here is my api.suite.yml

```
    class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - \Helper\Api
        - REST:
            url: http://localhost/backend/web/
            depends: PhpBrowser
            part: Json
```

However when I run this with coverage i get following error:

```
      [PHPUnit_Framework_Exception]                                                                                                                    
  file_get_contents(http://localhost/backend/web/c3/report/clear): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
```

After seeing into the apache/error.log there is this:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Codeception\\Exception\\ConfigurationException: Path for output not specified. Please, set output path in global config in /var/www/html/vendor/codeception/base/src
```

I think its problem with PhpBrowser configuration, when I used Yii module instead of PhpBrowser there wasnt exception, however there was always error 404. I'm kinda stucked here. Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Have you included c3 library to your application? https://github.com/Codeception/c3

Comment: yes, thats where the error is coming from

Comment: Your second error means that `paths: log:` parameter is missing in your codeception.yml file - https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/blob/2.2/codeception.yml#L3

Comment: it's set, in both codeception.yml -> in root directory and in backend/ which are tested

Comment: c3 writes error message to log dir,  `c3tmp/error.txt` file.